# Pagination Laravel 8 no result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am following a tutorial about Pagination in Laravel 8,
But it did not work ,
this is what I have done :

In BookingController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $bookings = DB::table('bookings')->paginate(1);
    return view('bookings.index')
        ->with('bookings', $bookings);
}
```

In Booking.php

```
class Booking extends Model
{
}
```

In index.blade.php

```
{{$bookings->links()}}
```

It is not showing any error but It is not working , do anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: You have the model `Booking.php`, but you don't use it if you use `DB::table('bookings')`... Your code should be `$bookings = Booking::paginate(1);`. Aside from that, do you actually have rows in your database? What is the output of `Booking::count();`?

Comment: Booking::paginate(1); I have used this one but same result

Comment: Booking::count(); returns 1

Comment: well sorry it works but with bad render ,the pagination was not showing because the record was 1

Comment: Try adding another row to your database; I don't think the `links()` method renders anything if there's only a single record in the database.

Comment: Yes it works but I have a bad render

Answer (score 1):

=>you can try this i can use this pagination links its work on laravel 8.

{{$bookings->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}